# param server C++ lists

Tags: ros, yaml-cpp, parameter, param-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm defining config vectors through the param server using yaml files:

sample: *velocity_controller/velocity_max: [0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5]*

If I want to parse these vectors from a python node I use this code:

*_velocity_max = array( rospy.get_param("velocity_controller/velocity_max") )*

However, in C++, using the *ros::param::getCached()* I'm only able to parse the following types: *string, int, double, bool or XmlRpcValue*.

How I can import my values into a *std::vector* ?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12628/param-server-c++-lists/) by [narcispr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1214/narcispr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 307 on 2012-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to convert the lists yourself from XmlRpcValue, see http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Retrieving_Lists

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [narcispr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1214/narcispr/) on 2012-01-16**:
Thank you! I can't understand how I skip this example :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Give my answer to [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/3289/how-to-write-and-parse-yaml-file-for-ros#5184) question a look. It allows you to look up parameters into a map. I use it to build an array of strings, but you could easily just use doubles instead.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Specifically for lists the [param server documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Retrieving_Lists) has a code example.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-01-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS groovy and forward you can now get vectors and dictionaries of primitives and strings without having to use the XmlRpc API: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/279

See the unit tests for examples, but it works like you'd expect it to work: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/9c133c6a761f73accbe674af9df1f64c0db49051/test/test_roscpp/test/src/params.cpp#L264

I've updated the wiki doc here:
http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Retrieving_Lists

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2014-05-21**:
Thanks for updating the wiki Jon. This API addition never got publicized enough, and addresses an important pain point in the roscpp API.